# Convert Eland dataframes to elasticsearch dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am exploring eland(https://eland.readthedocs.io/). I have a es_query to query the data from elastic search.

```
import eland as ed
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
df = ed.DataFrame(es, es_index_pattern="feed_data")
ed_df = df.es_query({
    "bool": {"must": [{"term": {"feed_num": 1234}}, {"term": {"num": 16}}]}})
print(ed_df)
```

The result for above lines is giving this output below

```
"capacity": {
    "1": null
},
"num": {
    "1": 16
},
"feed_num": {
    "1": 1234
}
```

I dont want these "1" to get printed. Earlier I was taking the output from elastic search hits  and was parsing them based on the output passing it pandas function.

```
But these **"1"** will be confusing to the client. 

**"feed_num": {
    "1": 1234
}**
```

Any suggestions if I want the output as

```
{
 "feed_num":1234
}
```

Based on these output I can play with multiple functions of pandas. I treied by json.dumps. and to_dict but not working

Comment: So `print(ed_df)` not return `DataFrame`, but dictionary?

Comment: I checked the type it is dataframe only